# How to restart a beamer presentation when you come to the last slide?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am trying to find to restart my presentation when I come to the last slide, I mean that the next slide It would be the first one, and next the second slide, and so on (a cyclic beamer). I used `\againframe` but It only repeats the slide.
Anyone could help me?

My code is:

```
\documentclass[handout,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}


%================ Paquetes 

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}%
\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse} 
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%\usepackage{style/poliStyles}
%\usepackage{style/tensorOperator}

% ===================== Temas
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usetheme{Berlin}



 %============================= Wallpaper
\title[]{\textcolor{black}{\vskip 1.5cm\textbf {Title}}}


%======================================== Set wallpaper
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle 
\end{frame}
%====================================== Table of content
%\AtBeginSection[]
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contenido}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%======================================
\section{Introducción}
\subsection{sismos lentos}
\subsubsection{Sismos lentos en México}
\subsection{sismos de baja frecuencia}
\subsection{Tremores volcánicos}
\begin{frame}{Introducción I}




\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introducción II}
Fueron descubiertos en Japón
\end{frame}

\section{Análisis de los datos}
\subsection{Procesado}
\begin{frame}{Análisis de los datos}
    
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- some pdf viewer allow you to automatically loop your presentation, e.g. adobe reader has this option:

[image]

- most pdf viewer will have a shortcut to go to the first page, e.g. try the <kbd>Home</kbd> key on your keyboard. If this does not work, have a look into the documentation of your viewer.
- if all other options fail, you can simply click the presentation icon from beamer's navigation symbols (you get them automatically if you remove the `handout` option):

[image]